# Unwanted horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, styles, scrollbar, navbar

I've tried everything to remove this scrollbar but no result.
Basically after making the navbar, suddenly there appeared a horizontal scroll bar. I think that's because of this. Code below.

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="home" class="active">Strona Głowna</a></li>
<li><a href="commands">Projekty</a></li>
<li><a href="features">Discord (wkrótce)</a></li>
<li><a href="about">YouTube</a></li>
<li><a href="store">Zespół</a></li>
<li><a href="store">English</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}



nav ul {
    display: flex;
}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav li a {
 margin:2px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background:#0986d9;
  font-size:12px;
  text-decoration:none;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.active{
  margin:2px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color:black;
  background:#69d4ff;
  font-size:12px;
  text-decoration:none;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

nav li a:hover{
  text-align: center;
  border:none;
  background:#11b6f7;
  color:black;

}
```

Just saying that similar problems didn't fix that. In the end, you can attach a link to the solution for this in case I didn't test/seen that.

Answer (score 0):

On your example is no scrollbar displayed.
But space-between was not working because you need to add it to the parent element where you want to use it. in this Case the #nav ul.

Just for the case, you can also add max-width: 100%; to nav and/or set overflow-x: hidden;

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="home" class="active">Strona Głowna</a></li>
<li><a href="commands">Projekty</a></li>
<li><a href="features">Discord (wkrótce)</a></li>
<li><a href="about">YouTube</a></li>
<li><a href="store">Zespół</a></li>
<li><a href="store">English</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}



nav ul {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}


nav li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav li a {
 margin:2px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background:#0986d9;
  font-size:12px;
  text-decoration:none;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.active{
  margin:2px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color:black;
  background:#69d4ff;
  font-size:12px;
  text-decoration:none;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

nav li a:hover{
  text-align: center;
  border:none;
  background:#11b6f7;
  color:black;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8eoLjz9/)

Comment: Tried both in all ways, didn't fix that. Any other ideas?

Comment: No sorry, because as you can see in the JDFiddle, there is no vertical scrollbar in the code you gave us. The problem must be somewhere else, and nobody can guess.